# Xamarin Forms - Run a hidden WebView without attaching it to the view

Tags: xamarin, webview, xamarin.forms

Currently my code creates an instance of a hidden class and initializes a WebView that should download JavaScript from the server. The problem is that if the WebView is not part of the main screen that the user is looking at, it doesn't load the URL.

My Simple App:

```
public partial class App : Application
{
    // set up Hidden WebView
    CompanySDK.FooClass foo = new CompanySDK.FooClass();

    public App()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        var page = new ContentPage();

        page = new DemoAppPage();

        MainPage = page;
    }

    protected override void OnStart()
    {
        // test a method call
        foo.test();
    }
}
```

Hidden WebView Class:

```
public class FooClass
{
    WebView browser = new WebView();

    public FooClass()
    {
        browser.Source = "https://companyserver.com/xyz";

        // make the browser invisible
        browser.SetValue(IsVisibleProperty, false);

        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("WebView Started for platform: " + Device.OS.ToString().ToLower());

    }

    public void test()
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Test Method ");

        String js = "alert('Test Method');";
        browser.Eval(js);
    }

}
```

If I change `FooClass` to be a `ContentPage` and add it as the main app view, I see calls to `companyserver.com`, but I can't have the WebView as part of the UI, as it should remain in the background / hidden. My debug prints show up in all cases, so I know the code is being called.

Is there a way to achieve what I'm after?

Comment: So I don't know the solution, but I know the problem. Xamarin.Forms uses a "renderer" to translate a Xamarin.Forms type into a native control (such as displaying a `UIWebView` when adding a `WebView` to a page). Now that process happens lazily, meaning the platform specific controls aren't even instantiated until they're about to be displayed. So if you never display the `WebView`, then there will never even be a `UIWebView` or Android `WebView` instantiated.

Comment: What if you add the `WebView` into your page? You can use `IsVisible` to make it transparent, and use an `AbsoluteLayout', `RelativeLayout` or `Grid` to place it behind your other content.

Comment: Well at least I understand what the problem is now. I'm not sure about the solution, however, because the WebView should get set up just by instantiating `FooClass` in the main application.

Comment: If you don't want to put the `WebView` into the layout, then you could use a platform specific service to instantiate a web view on each platform and load your Url in that.